# How to rewrite this code in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, tree

The current code is as follows. It is just for counting the descendant level of some node of a given node.

```
def count_level(self, node, given_node)
    parent_node = node
    descendant_level = 1
    while parent_node != given_node:
        parent_node = parent_node.parent
        descendant_level += 1
    return descendant_level
```

How to write it in a pythonic way?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: looks okay to me. Maybe you want to make your method static as `self` is not used at all. comprehensions will hardly help you there.

Comment: I don't know what's unpythonic about this...

Comment: You don't really need 'parent_node'.  Eliminate its definition and just use 'node' where you use 'parent_node'.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it looks too long to me.. thinking of writing it in a sum() expression. any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is perfectly fine, except you never check if you have hit the root, which means you can be stuck in the while loop. Another way to implement it would be recursively. I've dropped self, as it is never used, and added the root check.

```
def count_level(node, given_node,root):
    if node.parent==root:
       return 1
    elif node.parent==given_node:
       return 1
    else:
       return 1+count_level(node.parent,given_node,root)
```